# How to configure trusted hosting pattern for Docker containers

Tags: configuration

From Drupal 8, if my running [Docker project for Drupal](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal) is loading in my browser at...

`http://docker.drupalphp:17223/`

what should I put in my `sites/default/settings.php` file to approve the trusted_host_patterns settings?

I have tried **sooooo** many things, including this simple one...

```php
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^docker\.drupalphp$',
);
```

But no luck on getting the trusted host pattern approved.  Please help.

Here is a visual of my issue:

[image]

Comment: Is this the right settings file? It's not in like a local site folder?

Comment: when you say a "local site folder", do you mean like a Docker volume location on my Drupal project? The project is running locally on my computer through a Docker container. Its not live on the web.

Comment: sites/(sitename)/settings.php

Comment: using sites/default/settings.php

Comment: It would be awesome if we could debug what the attempted settings value is, not just a see a message that says "not enabled".  I feel that would solve a lot of headache.

Comment: How did you determine that `trusted_host_patterns` is the issue?

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: You don't really need this for local development. But the only things I can think of is: Flush cache. And: The file where you've set this is never included or at some later point there's an empty `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` set again. And: Some server-side caching enabled maybe.

Comment: @leymannx many thanks on all the tips provided. I will role with that for now and assume all the above.